# TFS 2015 Project Wiki vs Code Wiki

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015

We are using TFS 2015 **On Premise**, not in the cloud and I am trying to give access to *Stakeholders* so they can access the wiki. However, as a stakeholder I keep getting this error:

> TF400409: You do not have licensing rights to access this feature: Code

After researching the error it seems to be related to the fact that *Stakeholders* do not have access to view *Code Wikis* as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-readme-permissions?view=azure-devops). That link is for Azure DevOps and I am not sure if it applies to my case but I cannot find anything else so my assumption is it does apply. Even links within our TFS site, takes us to Azure DevOps for help and thus my assumption is it applies to us as well.

Here is a screenshot from the aforementioned link:

[image]

**Question**

What is the difference between *Code Wikis* and *Project Wikis*? It seems I need *Project Wikis* but how do I create a *Project Wiki*?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Code Wiki are not available on TFS server 2015. You need to use version TFS 2018 or above for this.

> **Project Wiki**
>
> Every team project can have a wiki. Use the wiki to share information
>   with your team to understand and contribute to your project.
>
> Each team project wiki is powered by a Git repository in the back-end.
>   When you create a team project, a Wiki Git repo is not created by
>   default. Provision a Git repository to store your wiki Markdown files,
>   or publish existing Markdown files from a Git repository to a wiki.

[image]

In the project page, you could directly choose to create project wiki.

**Code Wiki**

> **Content** that you already maintain in a Git repository **can be published to a wiki**. For example, this could be content written to
>   support a software development kit (SDK), product documentation, or
>   README file. You can publish multiple wikis within a single team
>   project.

More details about the difference of them, kindly refer our official doc here: 
**[Provisioned wikis vs. published code as a wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/provisioned-vs-published-wiki?view=azure-devops)**

As how to use them in Azure DevOps/TFS, you could also take a look at this step by step tutorial -- [Collaborating using Azure DevOps Wiki](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/wiki/)

Comment: You say they are both not available in TFS 2015 but I have a wiki in TFS 2015. Or do you mean code wiki is available but project wiki is not? Also do you have a link to a resource that says that?

Comment: Sorry.  Code Wiki are not available on TFS server 2015. You need to use version TFS 2018 or above for this. Only Project Wiki are available on TFS 2015. It's a little bit old.  If I remember correctly, Wiki on TFS 2015 should be the old style. Using welcome page to manage Readme.md file such as https://blogs.msmvps.com/molausson/2014/12/28/use-visual-studio-online-markdown-as-your-wiki/.  For TFS2018version and later, it  integrate Wiki Extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.wiki as the build-in feature.

Comment: More details about the difference about Provisioned wikis(project) vs. published code as a wiki.  You could take a look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/provisioned-vs-published-wiki?view=azure-devops Also update the reply.

Comment: You are telling me code wiki is not available on TFS 2015 but I have code Wiki. I am after project wiki as per my question. Your answer contradicts what I am noticing. So it's all confusing.

Comment: Hi CodingYoshi, Sorry for the confusing. What code wiki here is to push code/repo as a wiki. Not just use a file in the code/repo as a wiki. I tried on TFS 2015 update 4, but could not find a way to publish a repo as a wiki. Could you add what kind of wiki you have/using as a screenshot in your environment here. Which may make it more clearly.